# Notating 尾高型 pitch pattern in isolation

Tags: support, formatting

A classic example word-set for pitch-accent is 端/箸/橋.

With number notation or downstep notation we can distinguish all three:

```
端: はし⓪ or はし

箸: はし① or はꜜし

橋: はし② or はしꜜ
```

However with the (otherwise quite nice) tone annotation supported by the editor, I can't figure out a way to distinguish the 平板 and 尾高 patterns.

```
[はし]{HL}: This is definitely はし①/はꜜし

[はし]{LH}: Is this はし⓪/はし or はし②/はしꜜ?
```

I ask because dictionaries that use similar looking under-/over-line notation are able to represent a trailing drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to workaround this lack of functionality might to put in a space after し and marking it as L:

```
[はし ]​{LHL}
```

[はし ]{LHL}

However, I would argue that the LH notation is best used to notate actual realizations of pitch in an utterance, not the abstract pitch accent location in a standalone word. And differentiating heiban vs odaka feels like the latter to me. So personally I would use the downstep notation for it.

See [僕のこと, 私のこと pitch accent](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95187/%e5%83%95%e3%81%ae%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%ae%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-pitch-accent/95573#95573) for an example of how I use both notations for different purposes.